# Need Help on SQL QUERY in SFMC

Tags: marketing-cloud, sql

I am running the following query

```
select * from Policy
where policynumber in
(
select policynumber from [Email]
where newsletteroptin = 'Y'
and
Source NOT IN ('CWS')
)
```

I also have tried removing source and I am still getting records those newsleter options are N.

The results which I am getting it's pulling everything from email table even records those newsletteroptin option is N and even sources those do contain CWS...

I want to pull all records from Policy table those have newsletter optin to Y but source is not equal to CWS.

Comment: Please note `SQL` != `SOQL`.

Comment: Is there a 1:1 relationship between `policy` and `email` rows?

Comment: No. It's one(policy) to many(email).

Comment: What's the primary key on the target data extension?

Comment: Can you give us some sample rows from both data extensions and your desired output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you'll get into trouble in using wildcards instead of listing out the columns in your SFMC queries.  The columns are cached.

Second, I'd suggest selecting the `newsletteroptin` and `source` for verification -- assuming that there's a 1:1 relationship between `policy` and `email`.

```
select 
  p.policynumber
, e.newsletteroptin
, e.source
from Policy p
inner join Email e on p.policynumber = e.policynumber
where e.newsletteroptin = 'Y'
and e.source != 'CWS'
```

Comment: It's not one to one relation. It's one to many (policy to email).

Comment: ok, problem solved. I added all matching primary keys from both tables into inner join clause and problem solved.

so it becomes like this:

INNER join [Email] e on C.policynumber = e.policynumber
AND C.Email = E.Email
AND C.OriginalDOB = E.OriginalDOB

Where....

Thank you all, for helping me to resolve this issue.

Comment: I still think it'd be helpful if you updated your question with the answers to my two questions in the comments above.